# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: согласование

Компания "Рога и копыта" собирает друзей на своё совершеннолетие в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00.
Или правильнее будет: Компания "Рога и копыта" собирает друзей в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00 на своё совершеннолетие.
Или нет никакой разницы, правильны оба варианта? Или оба неправильны?

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта возможны, но они различаются оттенками значения.

Нейтральный вариант:  (1) Компания "Рога и копыта" собирает друзей на своё совершеннолетие в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00. Это естественное деление предложения на отдельные словосочетания: "собирает друзей на своё совершеннолетие", "в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00".

В варианте (2)  "Компания "Рога и копыта" собирает друзей в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00 на своё совершеннолетие" такой естественный порядок изменен, что позволяет выделить цель встречи - "на свое совершеннолетие".

Также варианты различаются по принципу деления сообщения на тему-рему.

(1)ТЕМА (известное): компания собирает друзей на своё совершеннолетие, РЕМА (новое)в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00.

(2)ТЕМА (известное): компания собирает друзей в ресторане "Харчи" 20 июля в 19.00, РЕМА (новое): на своё совершеннолетие.